# hard time mojo testing with maven-plugin-testing-harness

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

My plugin mojo test class leverages [`maven-plugin-test-harness`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/) to build the complete maven environment with all pom config, plexus container context and repo access.

The following should all actually work:

1. the test will refer to a test `pom.xml` in the plugin project's test resources directory
2. the mojo will be populated with defaults from the mojo annotations
3. all specified configuration in the test pom is accepted
4. the maven project object is initialised
5. all dependencies from the repo are available
6. the tests should pass in IntelliJ IDE as well as Maven on CI server

Because of the lack of concrete working examples I've been trying many different fixes using what I've collected from SO, and other blogs or articles online.

I am currently struggling to get the maven to resolve the artifacts. While I've got the dependency list from the maven project object, the artifact list is empty.

This is what I've built up by dissecting `AbstractMojoTestCase`.

I can't use `MojoRule` because JUnit5 doesn't use `@Rules` anymore.

Plus, some of the maven API calls are deprecated, but I couldn't find a new implementation. I think it won't come until mvn4. See the quote below.

```
@BeforeEach
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    cleanUp();
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource(TEST_POM);
    if (url == null) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(String.format(
                "Cannot locate %s", TEST_POM));
    }
    File pom = new File(url.getFile());
    //noinspection deprecation - wait on maven-plugin-testing-harness update
    MavenSettingsBuilder mavenSettingsBuilder = (MavenSettingsBuilder)
            getContainer().lookup(MavenSettingsBuilder.ROLE);
    Settings settings = mavenSettingsBuilder.buildSettings();
    MavenExecutionRequest request = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
    request.setPom(pom);
    request.setLocalRepositoryPath(settings.getLocalRepository());
    MavenExecutionRequestPopulator populator =
            getContainer().lookup(MavenExecutionRequestPopulator.class);
    populator.populateDefaults(request);
    DefaultMaven maven = (DefaultMaven) getContainer().lookup(Maven.class);
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession repoSession =
            (DefaultRepositorySystemSession)
                maven.newRepositorySession(request);
    LocalRepository localRepository = new LocalRepository(
            request.getLocalRepository().getBasedir());
    SimpleLocalRepositoryManagerFactory factory =
            new SimpleLocalRepositoryManagerFactory();
    LocalRepositoryManager localRepositoryManager =
            factory.newInstance(repoSession, localRepository);
    repoSession.setLocalRepositoryManager(localRepositoryManager);
    ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest =
            request.getProjectBuildingRequest()
                    .setRepositorySession(repoSession)
                    .setResolveDependencies(true);
    ProjectBuilder projectBuilder = lookup(ProjectBuilder.class);
    MavenProject project =
            projectBuilder.build(pom, buildingRequest).getProject();
    //noinspection deprecation - wait on maven-plugin-testing-harness update
    MavenSession session = new MavenSession(getContainer(), repoSession, 
            request, new DefaultMavenExecutionResult());
    session.setCurrentProject(project);
    session.setProjects(Collections.singletonList(project));
    request.setSystemProperties(System.getProperties());
    testMojo = (GenerateConfig) lookupConfiguredMojo(session,
            newMojoExecution("configure"));
    copyTestProjectResourcesToTarget(getContainer(), project, session);
}
```

**[UPDATE 2017-07-27]**: actually this now solves most of my problems.

Only a couple of minor issues now:

1. the code to grab the settings.xml is marked as `@Deprecated` so I assume there is a better way of doing it (using the `MavenSettingsBuilder.buildSettings()`)
2. probably quite a lot of the setup code is duplicating process that occurs anyway when running in native maven, but is required to run with JUnit in IntelliJ.

**[UPDATE 2017-08-01]**: test now needs to access some property files which would be on the classpath in a live environment in the `target/classes` dir.

Logically they are test resources in my maven-plugin project, so I have included them under the same directory as the test `pom.xml` in `src/test/resources/my-test-project` dir.

That didn't work, so I also tried `src/test/resources/my-test-project/src/main/resources` but that's also not good.

I am having a hard time establishing what exactly is on the plugin's classpath during the test, or working out how to cause it to be constructed correctly.

**[UPDATE 2017-08-02]**: although I've answered my own question (as opposed to extending this question), this whole thing isn't finished yet so I'm not marking this as answered quite yet.

And just for the record, these are the dependencies required:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**[UPDATE 2017-08-09]:**

I have to add some more functionality and discovered that the test was fine if the dependency it wanted to unpack was in the local repo already, but if not, it won't fetch it.

I now need to determine how to instruct maven to fetch the dependency from the remote repo.

I tried launching the dependency plugin and invoking `resolve` in the test setup, but it dies badly, I think there must be a simpler way.

Comment: First if you are opinion it is bad documented etc. why not helping to improve it ? Furthermore Can you show a full working example of your work what you have so far? Best would be having a github project where we can take a look at it?

Comment: Are you a committer? I'd happily contribute examples / improve the javadoc although that would depend on actually being able to get my tests fully functional. Although I see some questions on maven-plugin-test-harness here on SO, it's still really not enough to make the project a 'does-what-it-says-on-the-tin' kind of app. I couldn't find much googling either. I figure there must be discussions out there on the net somewhere - maybe an developer list email archive for maven that's not indexed by search engines?

Comment: You can search the users mailing list via: http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/. To help getting your tests running a full working example on github would be helpful ...and it would be great if you like to contribute to improvate that...

Comment: That does come up on google and I have already looked through it. There is nothing really there to guide someone trying to use it for the first time. I guess I should subscribe if there is a better chance of getting helpful advice than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to fetching dependencies from the remote repository.

Working with the maven internals like this and judging from the deprecated classes  and the amount of duplicated functionality, it gives me the strong impression that maven v4 will make this redundant.

One glitch with this setup routine is that it creates a local repository directory tree in the maven project directory. This is obviously not desirable but will need some more tweaking to solve.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource(TEST_POM);
    if (url == null) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(String.format(
                "Cannot locate %s", TEST_POM));
    }
    File pom = new File(url.getFile());
    Settings settings = getMavenSettings();
    if (settings.getLocalRepository() == null) {
        settings.setLocalRepository(
                org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
                        .defaultUserLocalRepository.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    MavenExecutionRequest request = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
    request.setPom(pom);
    ArtifactRepository artifactRepository =
            new org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.
                    DefaultArtifactRepository(
                    "id", settings.getLocalRepository(),
                    new DefaultRepositoryLayout());
    request.setLocalRepository(artifactRepository);
    MavenExecutionRequestPopulator populator =
            getContainer().lookup(MavenExecutionRequestPopulator.class);
    populator.populateFromSettings(request, settings);
    DefaultMaven maven = (DefaultMaven)
            getContainer().lookup(Maven.class);
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession repositorySystemSession =
            (DefaultRepositorySystemSession)
                    maven.newRepositorySession(request);
    SimpleLocalRepositoryManagerFactory factory =
            new SimpleLocalRepositoryManagerFactory();
    LocalRepositoryManager localRepositoryManager =
            factory.newInstance(repositorySystemSession,
                    new LocalRepository(settings.getLocalRepository()));
    repositorySystemSession.setLocalRepositoryManager(
            localRepositoryManager);
    ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest =
            request.getProjectBuildingRequest()
                    .setRepositorySession(repositorySystemSession)
                    .setResolveDependencies(true);
    ProjectBuilder projectBuilder = lookup(ProjectBuilder.class);
    ProjectBuildingResult projectBuildingResult =
            projectBuilder.build(pom, buildingRequest);
    MavenProject project = projectBuildingResult.getProject();
    MavenSession session = new MavenSession(getContainer(),
            repositorySystemSession, request,
            new DefaultMavenExecutionResult());
    session.setCurrentProject(project);
    session.setProjects(Collections.singletonList(project));
    request.setSystemProperties(System.getProperties());
    testMojo = (GenerateConfig) lookupConfiguredMojo(session,
            newMojoExecution("configure"));
    testMojo.getLog().debug(String.format("localRepo = %s",
            request.getLocalRepository()));
    copyTestProjectResourcesToTarget(getContainer(), project, session);
    resolveConfigurationFromRepo(repositorySystemSession, project);
}

private Settings getMavenSettings()
        throws ComponentLookupException,
            IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
    org.apache.maven.settings.MavenSettingsBuilder mavenSettingsBuilder
            = (org.apache.maven.settings.MavenSettingsBuilder)
                getContainer().lookup(
                    org.apache.maven.settings.MavenSettingsBuilder.ROLE);
    return mavenSettingsBuilder.buildSettings();
}

/**
 * This is ugly but there seems to be no other way to accomplish it. The
 * artifact that the mojo finds on its own will not resolve to a jar file
 * on its own in the test harness. So we use aether to resolve it, by
 * cloning the maven default artifact into an aether artifact and feeding
 * an artifact request to the repo system obtained by the aether service
 * locator.
 */
private void resolveConfigurationFromRepo(
        DefaultRepositorySystemSession repositorySystemSession,
        MavenProject project)
        throws ArtifactResolutionException, MojoExecutionException {
    org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact defaultArtifact =
            testMojo.getConfigArtifact();
    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(
            defaultArtifact.getGroupId(),
            defaultArtifact.getArtifactId(),
            null,
            defaultArtifact.getType(),
            defaultArtifact.getVersion());
    List<RemoteRepository> remoteArtifactRepositories =
            project.getRemoteProjectRepositories();
    DefaultServiceLocator locator =
            MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class,
            BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class,
            FileTransporterFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class,
            HttpTransporterFactory.class);
    RepositorySystem repositorySystem = locator.getService(
            RepositorySystem.class);
    ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest();
    artifactRequest.setArtifact(artifact);
    artifactRequest.setRepositories(remoteArtifactRepositories);
    ArtifactResult result = repositorySystem.resolveArtifact(
            repositorySystemSession, artifactRequest);
    defaultArtifact.setFile(result.getArtifact().getFile());
    testMojo.getLog().debug( "Resolved artifact " + artifact + " to " +
            result.getArtifact().getFile() + " from "
            + result.getRepository() );
}


/**
 * Need manual copy of resources because only parts of the maven lifecycle
 * happen automatically with this test harness.
 */
private void copyTestProjectResourcesToTarget(PlexusContainer container,
                                              MavenProject project,
                                              MavenSession session)
        throws ComponentLookupException, MojoExecutionException {
    Optional<Dependency> resourcesPluginDepOpt =
            project.getDependencies().stream()
                    .filter(d -> Objects.equals(d.getArtifactId(),
                            MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID))
                    .findFirst();
    // don't want to define the version here so we read it from what we have
    if (!resourcesPluginDepOpt.isPresent()) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException("Require " +
                MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID);
    }
    Plugin resourcePlugin = MojoExecutor.plugin(
            MojoExecutor.groupId(MAVEN_PLUGINS_GROUP_ID),
            MojoExecutor.artifactId(MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID),
            MojoExecutor.version(resourcesPluginDepOpt.get().getVersion()));
    MojoExecutor.executeMojo(resourcePlugin,
            MojoExecutor.goal("resources"),
            MojoExecutor.configuration(),
            MojoExecutor.executionEnvironment(
                    project, session,
                    container.lookup(BuildPluginManager.class)));
}
```

and here are the packages used, quite important to use the classes from the right package but easily confused:

```
import org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven;
import org.apache.maven.Maven;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.DefaultRepositoryLayout;
import org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequest;
import org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionResult;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.model.Dependency;
import org.apache.maven.model.Plugin;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingResult;
import org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenRepositorySystemUtils;
import org.apache.maven.settings.Settings;
import org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;
import org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession;
import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.impl.DefaultServiceLocator;
import org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.SimpleLocalRepositoryManagerFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.LocalRepository;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.LocalRepositoryManager;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactRequest;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResult;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.RepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.TransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.file.FileTransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporterFactory;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for so much complexity.

> I can't use MojoRule because JUnit5 doesn't use @Rules anymore.

Since version 3.2 you don't need to use @MojoRule, 7 years ago. Just follow the three steps below:

1. Your test class should extend AbstractMojoTestCase
2. Before your tests, call super.setUp()
3. Perform a lookup for your mojo:

   MyMojo myMojo = (MyMojo) super.lookupMojo("myGoal", "src/test/resources/its/my-test-mojo.pom.xml");

With that, you can work with Junit 5, Mockito, etc, with no overhead.

Comment: This scenario won't inject default values of `@Parameter`-s, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921236/how-to-make-mavenproject-injected-into-the-mojo-during-test-lookup

Answer (score 1):

Some comments in the maven source code for `MavenProject` said

> With changes during 3.2.2 release MavenProject is closer to being immutable after construction with the removal of all components from this class, and the upfront construction taken care of entirely by the @{ProjectBuilder}. There is still the issue of having to run the lifecycle in order to find all the compile source roots and resource directories but I hope to take care of this during the Maven 4.0 release (jvz).

I figure this whole maven plugin integration test thing is not going to work until then... and so looking around, I found [a great blog entry on invoking plugins](http://massol.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/Calling%20a%20Maven%20plugin%20from%20another%20plugin). So I invoked the `maven-resources-plugin` directly to get it to copy across what it was meant to. That's what the `copyTestProjectResourcesToTarget()` call does.

```
private void copyTestProjectResourcesToTarget(PlexusContainer container,
                                              MavenProject project,
                                              MavenSession session)
        throws ComponentLookupException, MojoExecutionException {
    logger.fine("generateConfig dependencies: ");
    project.getDependencies().forEach(d -> logger.fine(d.getArtifactId()));
    Optional<Dependency> resourcesPluginDepOpt =
            project.getDependencies().stream()
                    .filter(d -> Objects.equals(d.getArtifactId(),
                            MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID))
                    .findFirst();
    // don't want to define the version here so we read it from what we have
    if (!resourcesPluginDepOpt.isPresent()) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException("Require " +
                MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID);
    }
    Plugin resourcePlugin = MojoExecutor.plugin(
            MojoExecutor.groupId(MAVEN_RESOURCES_GROUP_ID),
            MojoExecutor.artifactId(MAVEN_RESOURCES_ARTIFACT_ID),
            MojoExecutor.version(resourcesPluginDepOpt.get().getVersion()));
    MojoExecutor.executeMojo(resourcePlugin,
            MojoExecutor.goal("resources"),
            MojoExecutor.configuration(),
            MojoExecutor.executionEnvironment(
                    project, session,
                    container.lookup(BuildPluginManager.class)));
}
```