# How to make MavenProject injected into the mojo during test lookup?

Tags: java, maven

This is my test (maven-plugin-testing-harness 3.3.0, junit 5.6.2):

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public final class MyMojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {
  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.setUp();
  }
  @Test
  public void executeIt() throws Exception {
   final File pom = new File("src/test/resources/my-test-pom.xml");
    final MyMojo mojo = MyMojo.class.cast(
      this.lookupMojo("mygoal", pom)
    );
    mojo.execute();
  }
}
```

This is what I have in `MyMojo` (maven-plugin-api 3.8.4):

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

@Mojo(name = "my", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public final class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
  @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)
  private MavenProject project;
}
```

The problem is that `mojo` returned by `lookupMojo()` doesn't have the `project` attribute set (it's `null`).

Some solution was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528763/how-to-populate-parameter-defaultvalue-in-maven-abstractmojotestcase), but I'm not sure how it  can work with JUnit 5.

Comment: Did you read https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html#integration-functional-testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with the same configurations as mentioned above. The plugin works fine but none of the tests having `lookupMojo()` seems to be working.

A similar test example can be referred [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html). There is a difference in the `setUp` method from your class `MyMojoTest` and example provided in the link.
`super.setUp();`  should be called instead of `this.setUp()` so as to initialize all the objects in `AbstractMojoTestCase` class.

The possible reason that the test case with `maven-plugin-testing-harness 3.3.0`  and `junit 5.6.2` will not work because they are not `compatible`.
The reasons are

1. `maven-plugin-testing-harness` was built to be compatible with `Junit4`. Latest update was a long [time](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/3.3.0) ago i.e. Dec 17, 2014. `Junit 4` and `Junit 5` are not compatible. We have to make use of `Junit-Vintage-Engine` to make it work.
2. `maven-plugin-testing-harness` was develop using `JDk-7` and minimum requirements for `Junit 5` is `Jdk-8`.
   Information from the `harness` plugin Manifest file

> Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.maven.plugin-testing 
> Built-By: igor 
> Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55 
> Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software
> Foundation Specification-Title: Maven Plugin Testing Mechanism

3. Maven version supported is also different for both the jars.
   [link](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugin-testing/blob/master/maven-plugin-testing-harness/src/site/fml/faq.fml)

Few other [links](https://khmarbaise.github.io/maven-it-extension/itf-documentation/background/background.html) confirm the same.

There are very few libraries and informational link available for plugin testing with Junit5. I could find only a handful of them, although I haven't tried them yet.

Library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>itf-assertj</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Few more Jupiter extension libraries in this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension)

Examples related to it.

- [Example 1](https://dzone.com/articles/maven-plugin-testing-in-a-modern-way-part-i)
- [Example 2](https://dzone.com/articles/maven-plugin-testing-in-a-modern-way-part-iv)
- [Example 3](https://dzone.com/articles/maven-plugin-testing-in-a-modern-way-part-ii)

Answer (score 2):

## Possible solutions

### Solution #1: Use `AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupConfiguredMojo()` method

Please, consider the implementation of the test class as an example: [maven-plugin-testing/ParametersMojoTest.java at maven-plugin-testing-3.3.0 · apache/maven-plugin-testing](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugin-testing/blob/maven-plugin-testing-3.3.0/maven-plugin-testing-harness/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/testing/ParametersMojoTest.java).

Considering this example, please, note the Mojo instantiation approach:

1. The `readMavenProject()` method.
2. The Mojo instantiation uses the `readMavenProject()` and `lookupConfiguredMojo()` methods:

   ```
   MavenProject project = readMavenProject( new File( "src/test/projects/default" ) );

   ParametersMojo mojo = (ParametersMojo) lookupConfiguredMojo( project, "parameters" );
   ```

This Mojo instantiation approach provides the instantiated Mojo with the correct `MavenProject` parameter value.

#### Some additional references

- Related [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064396/490018).

### Solution #2: Test `pom.xml` for plugin: Use project stub

It is necessary to update the test `pom.xml` file by introducing the `project` element (of the `configuration` element) with the stub.

For example:

```xml
<project>

    <…>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>touch-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <project implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.stubs.MavenProjectStub">
                        <groupId implementation="java.lang.String">test-group-id</groupId>
                        <artifactId implementation="java.lang.String">test-artifact-id</artifactId>
                        <version implementation="java.lang.String">1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </project>

                    <…>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### Some additional references

- An example. [maven-jar-plugin/pom.xml at maven-jar-plugin-3.2.2 · apache/maven-jar-plugin](https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/maven-jar-plugin-3.2.2/src/test/resources/unit/jar-basic-test/pom.xml).
- Related [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59896652/490018).